# Python: Thermopy module "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'burcat'"

Tags: python

I've just had to try and teach myself python for a project at work and it isn't going so well.

I'm trying to use the module "Thermopy" so that I can make programs for calculating gas dynamics etc.

I thought I had installed Thermopy correctly but when I went to just have a quick test of it, I couldn't get it to work, it imports the module fine and help(thermopy) seems to show it importing the right file (I think?) but If I then try and call any of the classes that should be in the module I get the error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'psicrometry' (Or whichever class I'm trying to call

e.g.
    import thermopy

```
help(thermopy)
print thermopy.__file__

thermopy.psicrometry.test_wark()
```

gives  the result

```
Help on package thermopy:

NAME
    thermopy

FILE
    c:\python27\lib\site-packages\thermopy-0.3-py2.7.egg\thermopy\__init__.py

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    burcat
    codata
    combustion
    constants
    iapws
    psicrometry
    units

DATA
    __version__ = '0.3'

VERSION
    0.3


C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\thermopy-0.3-py2.7.egg\thermopy\__init__.pyc

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\FGBD101000.wsatkins.com\GBBSB_Home$\BROW4631\My Documents\Python\thermopy testing",   line 7, in <module>
    thermopy.psicrometry.test_wark()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'psicrometry'
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated, I'm very new to all this and don't have any prior programming experience so apologies if I'm doing anything silly, but I couldn't understand any of the other answers I saw to similiar questions on the site.

Many thanks
James

Comment: try command `dir(thermopy)` and see what all modules you can use from `thermopy`

Comment: That gives ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__version__'] (There should be underscores before and after all those not sure how to do them in comments) I'm unsure why the other classes aren't appearing as the submodule files definetly exist in the folder.
One thing I thought, is the file path supoosed to go to thermopy\init.py? as opposed to just thermopy-0.3-py2.7.egg\thermopy ?  If so how do I change this? and why has it happened?